# How does adding 1'b1 to 8 bit reg work in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am absolute beginner in Verilog and I am wondering how does the addition statement work in this piece of program.

```
reg [7:0] hcount;
...
always @(posedge clk) begin
      if(!n_rst) begin
         hcount <= 'd0;
      end else if(hcount== (WIDTH-1)) begin
         hcount <= 'd0;
      end else begin
         hcount <= hcount + 1'b1;
      end
   end
```

I understand that `1'b1` expands to `8'b1` because hcount has 8 bit width and now the calculation will work with 8 bit now. But how exactly does that addition work? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog is a hardware description langue in a sense that it tries to describe *behavior* of real hardware. One of attributes of modern hardware is clock. Clock drives flops which synchronize data across different hardware devices.

Clock behavior in verilog is simulated by `posedge clk` (or negede), meaning that the corresponding *always* block will be executed if and only if clk switches to `1` from any other value (x, z, 0);.

So, in your case, there is supposed to be  a clock (clk) which gets generated somewhere in test bench. It periodically switches between 0 and 1.

As soon as it switches `0 -> 1` it gets executed. If condition is right, the `hcount <= hcount + 1'b1` will be executed. As you mentioned the compiler will zero-extend 1'b1 to the 8-bit value 00000001. The rest is the same as in any programming language, hcount will be incremented.

There is certain semantic associated with the non-blocking assignment, `<=`, but this would be a different question. For the purpose of your question it does not matter.

So, a result will be that a single increment will be done every clock cycle unless *n_rst* is '0'. Also, as soon as the counter reaches *WIDH - 1* it will be set to '0'. Only one operation is allowed at a single clock edge.